# Rails 4: session value never "expires" or dies when browser closes

Tags: security, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, session-cookies

*See update at end of question*

In Rails 4 I understand that sessions are, by default, only supposed to exist for the browsing session.  If you closed your browser, the sessions should no longer exist.

However, I'm not finding that to be the case.  I have a Rails 4 app using all the defaults provided by Rails.  I was working on some authentication code and ran into this problem.

When the user logs into the system, they have the option to "remember me" via a checkbox.  When they check the box, the session should have an expiration of 2 weeks.  The goal is that when the user logs into the system and closes his browser, he can then open the browser up again and use the app without having to authenticate again.

On the flip side, if the user does NOT want to check the "remember me" box and logs in to the app and closes the browser, when the browser opens again the user should be required to authenticate again because his session "expired" when the browser closed.

The problem is that my sessions never go away.  I tested some simple code where on page 1 I set a session variable in the controller and then on page 2 I display that session.  When I close the browser and go to page 2 (not page 1 so session is not set again), the session still exists as it did before.

I thought sessions were supposed to expire when the browser closed by default?  I have also tried this with "cookies" instead of sessions and get the same result.

In short, how can I get a session/cookie that expires/dies when the user closes their browser?  It doesn't seem very secure to me to have all sessions persist if the user doesn't want them to, and I'm not going to have my users delete their cookies everytime they close their browser (may be on a public computer where their login info should ONLY persist until they close the browser).

**Update**
I think I found what may be causing the problem.  I'm using Chrome as my browser and I had it set to "remember where I left off" when the browser closes and opens.  This seems to save all sessions/cookies.  I verified this with Gmail as well.  If you have the "remember where I left off" set, but don't set the remember me token in Gmail, Gmail opens right back up when you close/open browser.  If you tell Chrome to open a new tab on open, then Gmail sends you to the login page like I expect.

So that solves one problem, but the overall problem still persists.  How can I make this "secure"?  Let's say you're at a public computer, and a malicious user sets the browser to "remember where I left off" when the browser opens.  So you login to an app (such as Gmail) but don't check the "remember me" box.  So when you close the browser you expect your login to be "secure".  But if another user opens the browser back up, he's already logged into your app.

Is this something I can feasibly prevent?  If Gmail has this flaw (with an army of very intelligent developers) should I be bothered that this situation exists?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The browser "remember where I left off" functionality was indeed the problem.  Removing that option resulted in the "expected" behavior for my cookies/sessions.

Comment: Either that, or in Firefox, I closed the tab and then restarted the browser. Session is lost then. Thanks for catching this!